# How to fix Groovy Grails Tool Suite 3 extreme memory usage

Tags: eclipse, grails, memory, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Groovy Grails Tool Suite always takes more than 3000M of memory. Even at start.

Heap status show about 2500M

How can I fix this, it's not supposed to take that much. I always have to restart my IDE because it's too slow.

I've already upgraded my GGTS.ini:

-Xms320m
-Xmx3072m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m

Comment: I never see the IDE take all this at start, but I saw this one time that I opened a large file (groovy sql inserts for tests), the solution was split the file in more than one.

Comment: That is wayyy too much memory.  You shouldn't need to use that much.  Does memory usage creep up over time?  There could be a memory leak in the IDE.  Also, are you using the 4.2 or 3.8 version?  What platform and is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I'm using groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e4.2-win32-x86_64 (based on 4.2 on windows 7 64bit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Close unused project
2. Deactivate auto-build
3. Recreate your workspace (Back it up first!)
4. Others solutions: http://blog.normation.com/2010/05/24/optimizing-eclipse-performances/