# GGTS/STS 3.4.0 very slow on groovy files

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm using GGTS 3.4.0.RELEASE (64 bit) on Windows 7 and finding that the IDE is very slow when editing groovy files.

I can be typing, copying, pasting or trying to save when the IDE starts to hang. Sometimes it'll come back and let me continue, but mostly I have to kill the javaw.exe process and start it up again.

I've assumed its something to do with the Eclipse content assist which is causing this slowdown. I've turned off all content assist (Windows Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced) which has helped a bit, but it still feels sluggish.

Any suggestions?

### EDIT

I'm running GGTS based on Eclipse 4.2.

Comment: I uncheck 'Build Automatically' when I'm doing grails dev in GGTS. That tends to improve things quite a bit. Also, how big is your heap? I recommend setting it to at least 2GB, preferably 4GB (-Xmx4096m in GGTS.ini)

Comment: I've previously only given GGTS 1 or 1.5GB. Running on 2GB now with content assist back on and build auto checked. Seems to be behaving itself a bit better now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix Groovy Grails Tool Suite 3 extreme memory usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515704/how-to-fix-groovy-grails-tool-suite-3-extreme-memory-usage)